# Where can I find more detailed help about apoc relationShipFilter in Neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I used some apoc funtions (thx to [InversFalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92359/inversefalcon)). And I found some helpful information on this [site](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/)

But the relationShipFilter is just used in some function, but never explain detailed :)

There is some example, but not the full syntax. I want to exclude a relation, and I hope there is a syntax for it.

Here is a code, where I want to use it:

```
                IStatementResult result = session.Run(
                $"         MATCH (g:Graph)                                     \n" +
                $"         WHERE g.Database = '{Name}'                         \n" +
                $"           AND g.Name     = '{graph.Name}'                   \n" +
                $"          CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes( g, {{ }}) YIELD node \n" +
                $" DETACH DELETE node                                          \n" );
```

And the `apoc.path.subgraphNodes` takes a parameter relationshipFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship syntax and examples are [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_relationship_filter), but there currently isn't a means to exclude relationships.

Instead you would need to get all relationship types in the graph, filter out those you don't want, and join the remaining types into a string that you can pass to the filter, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53563565/92359) to a similar question.